# Linux netcat listener (nc -l) hung

Tags: linux, google-chrome, mac, browser, netcat

On my Raspberry Pi 3 Terminal (Linux) I typed the following and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
printf 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved\r\nLocation: https://www.eff.org/' | nc -l 2345
```

The Raspberry Pi 3 is part of my home network with a fixed address of 192.168.0.8.
Then, on my mac I typed the following into my browser (Chrome) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
192.168.0.8:2345
```

I can see the browser's GET request on my Linux Terminal (Raspberry Pi), but the `nc` listener gets stuck and does not send the reply (the HTTP 302 redirect message) to the browser.

Only when I stop the `nc` program by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the browser receives the reply message and displays the `https://www.eff.org` website.

Has anyone an idea why the `nc` listener gets stuck instead of sending the reply and close the connection?

Comment: (1) How do you know that the `nc` process is “stuck”?  Have you done an `strace` or sniffed the network?  (2) But first, try adding another `\r\n` to the end of the `printf` text string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your problem. When I connect with another `nc` instead of a browser, I see the reply is being sent immediately. I think your browser also receives the reply but since `nc` doesn't terminate the connection, the browser doesn't know it's all and it's OK to proceed with redirection.

(Note: during my tests I needed the final `\r\n` in the reply from `nc` to successfully redirect my browser, therefore all my examples use this fix.)

---

#### Edit: simple fix

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_messages.htm) I have found the following:

> HTTP requests and HTTP responses use a generic message format of RFC 822 for transferring the required data. This generic message format consists of the following four items.
>
> - [...]
> - [...]
> - An empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) 
>     indicating the end of the header fields
> - [...]

So your reply should be:

```
printf 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved\r\nLocation: https://www.eff.org/\r\n\r\n' | ...
```

After receiving this, your browser should continue with redirection, terminating the connection to `nc` on its own behalf. In early December 2017 it works with Opera and Vivaldi; it doesn't work with Firefox, Chrome or Safari, for which you may need another fix (see below).

---

---

#### Original, now inferior answer (it may still be useful for non-HTTP communication with `nc`)

According to [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/880289) you need to use `-c`, `-q` or similar option, depending on `nc` implementation.

In my Debian I have the `-q` capable version installed. Then

```
printf 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved\r\nLocation: https://www.eff.org/\r\n' | nc -q 0 -l -p 2345
```

works fine (note I also need `-p` to specify port). The explanation is:

> `-q seconds`
>   after `EOF` on `stdin`, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever (default).

---

If your `nc` has no proper option then the workaround may be to detect communication from a client and kill the entire command line. An example that works in my Debian, `bash`:

```
printf 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved\r\nLocation: https://www.eff.org/\r\n' | nc -l -p 2345 | { read foo; sleep 1; kill 0; }
```

When running a pipe, `bash` places every process in a single process group; `kill 0` sends signals to its entire process group. This way `nc` is killed about 1 second after any request is received that triggers `read`.

Comment: Thanks!

I tried the simple fix by adding \r\n\r\n at the end of the string as you suggested. This only works on the Opera browser (latest version). However with Firefox, Chrome or Safari (all latest versions) the process still gets stuck.

But when I add the `-q 0` option to the `nc` command, then it works in all browsers.

Comment: @ThomasGrusz Thank you. I tested with Vivaldi and added a browser compatibility note to my answer -- for future users.